# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater large = s > cutoff

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

```
sns.lmplot(x='day_diff',y='add_child_21',data=mean, hue='treatment',ci=90,height=6,aspect=1.4, fit_reg=True)
```

This code fails to plot the LM regression on the left side. I have no missing or infinite values.

*ERROR: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater large = s > cutoff*

[image]

Comment: hard to tell what went wrong. works ok for me with simulated data. Can you post the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your data and plotted, i don't get the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andrahiriscau/data/main/data.xls")

sns.lmplot(x='day_diff',y='add_child_21',data=df,
           hue='treatment',ci=90,height=6,aspect=1.4, fit_reg=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Might be some issue with my Python

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: It was an environment issue. I created a new environment for the project and it works.  Note: Jupyter started working only the next day, but the code run from the command line immediately.

Comment: hmmm there must be something wrong with the installation in the environment then. you are using conda i guess.. can be a bit problematic